# why return 0 in main function uploaded to microcontroller?

Tags: c, atmega

I was taught that the `return` at the end of `main` function is a signature to the program, which indicates whether the program exited successfully.

It seems like this idea does not hold for in microcontrollers, because you write a program in a `while(1)` loop, not even using any operating system like FreeRTOS.

Why, in such a case, would you `return 0` at the end of `main`? Who or what receives the return?

Comment: I don't understand your question, because when violets are red, not even I can follow.

Comment: In C `void main(void)` is valid, it's unspecified what happens when the function returns, but it is valid. And if you're writing the main function of an operating system, and the only way to exit that main function is to power off the system or programatically restart it, then who cares what you return, because it's not going to return anyway. ***On the other hand***, if you write a "normal" process that is supposed to have a beginning *and* n end, then you should probably be following the normal "standard" and return `0` for okay, and a small positive value for "failure".

Comment: I don't understand and I don't use return in the main function of my microcontrollers. There's an infinite loop, I stay in it. If an error that I can't manage happens I let the watchdog restart the microcontroller, but I don't return from main.

Comment: If the return value is not used in a stand-alone environment, a good compiler will optimize out the `return 0;`.  As `int main()` can be recursively called, return an `int`, either explicitly or implicitly is good coding.

Comment: See the linked duplicate. Several good answers there, some of them address "freestanding systems". Also see [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/55767/who-receives-the-value-returned-by-main) question over at E.E, the answer by yours faithfully should answer your question as well.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: `void main` is only valid for freestanding environments.

Comment: @Olaf Even hosted systems allow implementation-defined forms of main, since C99. The standard isn't really clear. See the linked duplicate, particularly [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/584518) answer.

Comment: @Lundin: The exact text is really not good phrased, as it is not clear what the "or in some other implementation defined..." part binds to: the whole or just the parameters (I do prefer the parameters ony, but there should be a defect/unclear report for the paragraph). But the environment can add additional restrictions. Do you know any hosted environment which does **not** require main to return an `int` result?

Comment: @Olaf MS DOS! :) And probably various old versions of Solaris. Also some hosted systems, most notably [Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx), use completely implementation-defined forms of main.

Comment: @Lundin: I just asked about the result type, not the arguments (the arguments are not relevant here). And for the arguments: IIRC they still allow for `int, char **`, but add more arguments. Btw. POSIX does the same.

Answer (score 2):

On a [**hosted environment**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2), The signature of `main` allows for two basic variants:

```
int main(void)

int main(int, char **)   // or synonym like char *[]
```

Strictly speaking the `return 0` is never required for `main`, as the standard clearly states that [5.1.2.2.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.3):

> If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, a return from the initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value returned by the main function as its argument reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0. If the return type is not compatible with int, the termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.

By long time established convention `0` means "no error" on such systems (that's the reason for the default result).

---

Said that, a bare metal controller is typically a [**freestanding environment**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.1). For such environments, the signature of `main` is not specified. Actually not even which function is called as entry to the application program is not defined, but left to the environment. Using `main` is just a common informative convention here. It often has a signature of

```
void main(void)
```

Even better, they define

```
_Noreturn void main(void)
```

That means `main` shall never ever return.

However, some systems allow `main` to return and flag for special actions, e.g. cold reset, hot reset, signal fatal failure (like busy-blink an LED), power off, etc. So you require one of the classic signatures here.

Note all this is beyond the standard and has to be defined by your execution environment.

---

Briefly: `return 0` from `int main(...)` is **not** required for a hosted environment, but it is good style to be explicitly state: "Yes, there is no error here". For a freestanding environment like your's Check the documentation and/or startup code for the correct signature and the allowed results.

Comment: Strictly speaking a `return some_value;` is required  if code performs a call to `main()` in either a hosted or non-hosted environment (and no preceding `exit` nor infinite loop).  OTOH, I'm not a fan of code calling its own `main()`.

Comment: @chux: No! for a freestanding environment, the standard does not have **any** requirement on how the application is started (I think I wrote that). Neither for the name, nor the parameters or result. IOW, there is no special (no declaration allowed, automatic `return 0` ) `main` in freestanding code. Just a normal function which **may** be called `main`, but need not (and you have to declare it). See 5.1.2.1p1. And there is also no requirement for `exit` or `abort`, just few mandatory headers which don't contain any code.

Comment: @chux: But I agree, any application entry-function(s) should not be called recursively.

Comment: 5.1.2.2.3: refers to an "a return from the initial call".   A subsequent call (recursion) of `main()` is not the initial call and does not enjoy the missing `exit/return 0;` option specified in 5.1.2.2.3.  So if code calls `main()`, then `main()` needs an explicit return value.